# How can I solve this OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error in Netbeans as it doesn't affect my program but the opening of my panels?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am doing a school project (airline reservation system). I am doing this project in java using netbeans IDE. One of my classes is the FindFlights class - it is a jPanel made directly using netbeans palette rather than hard coding of my own to create the GUI.

It was working all along, when suddenly one day I tried to open the jpanel to add and edit some of my gui - It got stuck and is on a standstill (loading). The notifications bar say it is a OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

However, the program runs as usual without any issues. But my GuI panel won't show as it is stuck when I try to open it and therefore cannot be edited. How can I solve this problem in ordr to edit the GUI? I was suggested -Xmx (e.g2g) command to be put in VM Options but it did not work.

Vignesh

Comment: Try printing a stack trace at the moment your code freezes/runs out of memory (unless you already have one, in which case paste it here along with relevant code).

Comment: There isn't really a stack trace. The freeze/run out of memory occurs when I try to open the panel with which I want to work with - not when trying to run the program. It just displays the error described above on the notifications bar in Netbeans when it becomes frozen i.e. the panel when opening it not the running of the program    . The program runs normally but I cannot edit the jPanel using the built-in palette. Yet, I have pasted the code applicable above.

Comment: Since I do not know what causes the error, do I have to print the entire class(s). There are more than 1 class, associated with this since I have my own methods.

Comment: download visualvm or eclipse mat to find memory leaks